# Is it possible to recover deleted files from C: drive reset?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, data-recovery, file-recovery

Hi so I was forced by Windows to reset (PC was crashing on startup, resetting was the only option) and couldn't back files stored in my C: Drive (I did an solo drive reset on my primary drive which is C) and lost a .txt file containing very important details (I know, I'm such a donkey for not backing it up) and now is causing me a problem. Is there any, and I mean it, ANY way to recover a .txt/any type of file from my reset? (this reset happened like 5 days ago or near it) oh and I use an SSD (Kingston 120GB SSD) for my primary/boot up device. I would also like to mention that the file I am trying to recover is in my Desktop if that helps/clears up things. Thank you for taking the time on reading this and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file's contents might have been over-written and destroyed.
If there is any chance of recovery, you should really take the disk out of
the computer, put it in another computer and run file-recovery products.

You may try products from the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).
I suggest starting with MiniTool.

Some other recovery products you could try are :
[Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva),
[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk),
[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).